# I have a image in layout and i generate xdpi,hdpi etc but my layout show error

Tags: android, directory, drawable, mdpi

layout show error and images  also does not show when i open it in android package:

[image: image description]

what is happening I don't know

Comment: Your folder names should be hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi,large,xlarge

Comment: You are putting drawable hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi folders inside drawable. get them separate folders. i mean outside of drawable folder. try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have created drawable folder in wrong location you can't create drawable-ldpi or drawable-mdpi etc folders in drawable folder but the they structure like this.

[image]

this is how the different drawable folder were created in files system and android studio show this something like this:

[image: image for android studio]

to create a drawable in specific folder append with -hdpi, -ldpi, -mdpi, -xhdpi, -xxhdpi, -xxxhdpi same for mipmap and values folders.

[image: image for creating drawable folder]
hope this will help you.

Comment: then what can i do pls help

Comment: go to drawable location first

Comment: right click on drawable folder and select Show in Explorer option.

Comment: it made xml-(hdpi)

Comment: where you have made these changes?

Comment: in android>drawable>make resource directory

Comment: please give explaination step by step I am new in android

Comment: dear simply go to drawable folder and select drawable-hdpi folder and press delete.

Comment: @sdevis have you understand this?

Comment: tell me further

Comment: ask me what you want to?